# Required vaccinations for Eastern Europe

Tags: health, eastern-europe

What vaccinations and medicines are required for travel to Eastern Europe?

Comment: "Eastern Europe" is very generic term, I think you should be more precise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Eastern Europe"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Europe#Definitions) is kind of a broad term, and depending on definition may consist of quite different countries.

In any case, [Grzenio is right](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/10880/583) in that the recommended vaccinations are pretty much the same as for Western Europe (or North America). (MastaBaba is also right that these are *recommendations*, not requirements.) To be more specific:

**Vaccines recommended for all**

- [DPT / DTwP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPT_vaccine)
- [MMR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMR_Vaccine)
- [Hepatitis A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_A_vaccine) (some countries, like Georgia)

**Vaccines also to be considered**, based on a personal risk estimate

- ([Hepatitis A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_A_vaccine))
- [Hepatitis B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hepatitis_B_vaccine)
- [TBE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick-borne_encephalitis) (some countries, like Estonia, Hungary or Ukraine)

<sup>Source: [rokote.fi](http://www.rokote.fi/Matkailijan-rokoteopas/201/Maakohtaiset-rokotussuositukset.aspx), a Finnish website whose recommendations come from the [National Institute for Health and Welfare](http://www.thl.fi/en_US/web/en)</sup>

Comment: Worth mentioning, that for example TBE is only relevant if you're going to countryside or forests. Not relevant if you only planning to do sightseeing in cities.

Comment: +1 Your list corresponds to what I what I have been told but contradicts your first paragraph: TBE and Hepatitis B are less of an issue in Western than Central or Eastern Europe.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know the recommended vaccinations are pretty much the same as in Western Europe. Depending where you are from obviously, you should have taken them when you were a child.

Having said that, it is always useful to discuss it with your local travel clinic.

Answer (score 2):

Depending where you want to travel to you could check out the [CDC destination page](http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/list.htm#u), which gives you a list of countries and possibly required vaccinations.

Though it may be more beneficial to give an indication of where exactly you're going to get a more definitive or streamed down list.

Comment: From the top of my mind, I don't think vaccinations are *required* for any destination in eastern Europe, though plenty might be *advised*.

Comment: @MastaBaba From having lived there and having traveled extensively standard US vaccination set is more then sufficient though in Ukraine/Russia/Belorussia rural areas Cholera vaccination might be prudent.